# inserting Json data from url into postgresql database

Tags: python, json, postgresql

The query i am using it this:

```
ST = "INSERT INTO oky (file_number,occurred_on, road_condition, weather, relation_roadway, primary_factor, alignment, surface_type, district, surface_condition, tot_veh, location_kind, st_name, zone, subzone, subzone, access_control, geolocation_address,st_number, road_type, lighting, manner_of_collision,geolocation_city, crash_date,crash_time, st_type, closest_street, geolocation) 
      VALUES ( "\+str(dbfile_number)+ ',' + str(dboccured_on)+',' +dbroad_condition+ ',' +dbweather+ ',' +dbRelation_roadway+ ',' +dbPrimary_factor+ ',' +dbAlignment+ ',' +dbSurface_condition+ ','+dbTot_ve+dbRelation_roadway+ ',' +dbPrimary_factor+ ',' +dbAlignment+ ',' +dbSurface_condition+ ','+dbTot_veh+ ',' +dbLocation_kind+ ','+dbSt_name+','+bZone','+dbSubzone+',' +dbAccess_control+','+dbGeolocation_address+','+dbst_number+','+dbLightning+','+dbManner_of_collision+',' +dbGeolocation_city+','+dbCrash_date+','+dbCrash_time+','+dbSt_type+','+dbClosest_street+','+dbClosest_street+','+dbGeolocation+")"
```

The error i am getting is this:

> SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
>   from the script

Can anyone please help me by telling what i am doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
ST = "INSERT INTO oky (file_number,occurred_on, road_condition, weather, relation_roadway, primary_factor, alignment, surface_type, district, surface_condition, tot_veh, location_kind, st_name, zone, subzone, subzone, access_control, geolocation_address,st_number, road_type, lighting, manner_of_collision,geolocation_city, crash_date,crash_time, st_type, closest_street, geolocation) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);" 

data = (str(dbfile_number), str(dboccured_on), dbroad_condition, dbweather, dbRelation_roadway, dbPrimary_factor, dbAlignment, dbSurface_condition, dbTot_ve, dbRelation_roadway, dbPrimary_factor, dbAlignment, dbSurface_condition, dbTot_veh, dbLocation_kind)  #Add the required data. 

cursor.execute(ST, data)
```

Comment: I get tuple index out of range

Comment: hello Rakesh I have sent you the python file via rakesh.ram.ar@gmail.com please look at it assist thanks